# Microsoft Lumia 540 - unable to find images received via bluetooth

Tags: photos, bluetooth, lumia-540

I use Microsoft Lumia 540. I received nearly 450 image files over bluetooth last day. Unfortunately, I am not able to see any of them in my phone now. Checked Photos->Saved pictures, downloads etc. When 'Storage sense' app is checked, I see 1.6GB used space for 'Others' folder. But, couldn't find anything inside it. Connected the phone to laptop. The other folder is not even listed. Please advice.

Comment: Not sure but have a look in File Explorer if you are on Windows Mobile 10. Maybe you can find it there.

Comment: images received will go to sd card-> pictures-> SAVED pICTURES

Comment: I discovered that windows phone8 prompts you to save a file transferred to it via Bluetooth otherwise the file will be missing after transfer is completed

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Storage Sense.
2. Check the default save location of Photos.
3. If it is phone go to, *Phone->Pictures->Saved Pictures* or *Phone->Downloads*.
4. If it is in SDcard check the *Saved Pictures* and *Downloads* folder in SDcard.
5. If you canot see it, connect your phone to PC and look in the same folders.

**Note** : Use the [Files app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL) or the built-in File explorer(in case of windows 10) to navigate. Some 3rd party apps may not show all files.

> Connected the phone to laptop. The other folder is not even listed.

The other section mentions the filetype that are not yet anslysed or recoganised by windows mobile. It does not correpond to a folder. There is no others folder. All recieved contents are stored in Saved pictures or Downloads.